# How to find double letters that are side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find doubled letters that are next to each other and replace them with a single letter.

But I don't know how to do the condition if they are side by side

Example:

- aaabc --> abc
- aaabbbcccddd ---> abcd
- aaabbbcccddda ---> abcda
- aabc --> abc
- aabbccbc --> abcbc
- ababab --> **do nothing**
- aba --> **do nothing**
- hello world --> helo world
- Alexandre --> **do nothing**

```py
string = "hello world"

duplicates = []
for char in string:
    if string.count(char) > 1:
        if char not in duplicates:
           duplicates.append(char)
   
print(*duplicates)
```

Comment: There are 3 answers in that ^ link, 2 that uses built-in modules and 1 that uses a "pure" loop going through the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go;

```
string = list("hellllllo worrld")

newStr = ''

for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] != string[i-1]:
        newStr += string[i]


print(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
string = "aaababaaaacccccdddaad"

temp = string[0]
for char in string[1:]:
    if char == temp[-1]:
        continue
    temp += char

print(temp)
```

Output:

```
ababacdad
```